# How do I use PowerShell within a batch file FOR command?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory

I'm trying to generate a date string for an LDAP query compatible with the Active Directory `whenChanged` field.  I'm pulling AD data into CSV using CSVDE and need an LDAP query that will filter the results to those items changed within the last 2 days.  I pieced together the following FOR command to generate the first part of the comparison string based on a few examples found here on Stack Overflow:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i in (`PowerShell $date^= [DateTime]::Today.AddDays^(-2^)^; $date.ToString^('yyyyMMdd'^)`) DO SET daysAgo = %i
```

This FOR command works fine from the command prompt, but bombs inside a batch script, w/ the following output:

```
:Today.AddDays(-2); was unexpected at this time.
```

What's causing the command to bomb?  Thanks.

Comment: Solved.  Variables need to be prefixed w/ `%%` inside a batch file.

Comment: Suggestion: If you have solved this then answer your own question and (when permitted) accept that answer. (PS. all of your problem can be solved in PSH: AD and CSV are both included without external components.)

Comment: Power shell does allow cmd commands, you know that right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm stealing his juice... `FOR` iterator variables in a batch file need to have a double percent sign, `%%`. So, your line would look like this

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i in (<snipped-powershell-command>) DO SET daysAgo=%%i
```